# Best way for storing millions of records a day of data that can be grouped for statistic purposes?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, database-design, ip-geolocation

I'm developing a custom tracking tool for marketing campaigns. This tool is in the middle between the ads and the landing pages. It takes care of saving all data from the user, such as the info in the user-agent, the IP, the clicks on the landing page and the geocoding data of the IPs of the users (country, ISP, etc).

At the moment I have some design issues:

- The traffic on these campaigns is very very high, so potentially I have millions of rows insert a day. This system can have more than one user, so I can't store all this data on a single table because would become a mess. Maybe I can split the data in more tables, one table per user, but I'm not sure about this solution.
- The data saving process must be done as quickly as possible (some milliseconds), so I think that NodeJS is much better than PHP for doing this. Especially with regard to speed and server resources. I do not want the server to crash from lack of RAM.
- I need to group these data for statistic purposes. For example, I have one row for every user that visit my landing page, but I need to group these data for showing the number of impressions on this specific landing page. So all these queries need to be executed as faster as possible with this large amount of rows.
- I need to geocode the IP addresses, so i need accurate information like the Country, the ISP, the type of connection etc, but this can slow down the data saving process if I call an API service. And this must be done in real-time and can't be done later.

After the saving process, the system should do a redirect to the landing page. Time is important for not losing any possible lead.

Basically, I'm finding the best solutions for:

- Efficiently manage a very large database
- Saving data from the users in the shortest time possible (ms)
- If possible, make geocode an ip in the shortest time possible, without blocking execution
- Optimize the schema and the queries for generating statistics

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use ELK stack in this case.

Comment: Take advantage of server logs; store the raw data in a single table; use background tasks to handle IP lookup for geocoding; don't dismiss PHP as slow and memory hungry when used for this purpose, I've done logging for sites with million of hits per day with PHP without it being an overhead

Comment: Otherwise, your question is way to broad for StackOverflow

Comment: Hi @Rahul, can you explain how can I use ELK stack?

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker, but potentially I will have a raw data table with billions of records.

Comment: Yes, and! If you want to do this seriously for large volume data, you use background tasks to move that data to a normalized structure of tables for doing your analysis/querying

Comment: @MarkBaker did you advice to split in some tables, one per user?

Comment: No I didn't advise that; create a set of tables that's nomalized for your data structures and queries, and indexed appropriately; and use a background process to populate that from your raw data table... as you populate these tables, remove/archive that data from your raw table

Comment: Depending upon what you're doing with the data and how much realtime availability you need, sometimes it makes sense to just write each new incoming set of data to a line in a log file.  That can be done super-fast and with very little resources.  Then, you can have another process that grabs the data from the log file and adds it into appropriate databases as needed and can perhaps so so by processing chunks of data at a time rather than just one piece set of data at a time.  This can then include more time consuming tasks such as goeocoding without worry about delaying the recording of data.

Comment: These solution solves the problem of saving the data in the shortest possible time, but I have many doubts on the aggregate queries performances when the database will weigh gigabytes. The main problem is this. I think that I can also use MongoDB or others noSQL databases for saving the data rapidly, but when I need to aggregate these data for statistic?

Comment: @angelocala94 You can use Kafka to get logs from different servers, process them via Elastic Search and show analytics data via Kibana. Check it out online.. it's a pretty famous stack. Best if you can check out multiple sources. It can handle dozens of GBs of data per day following all your requirements. https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=ELK%20stack

Comment: @Rahul yes I've searched it online, but not seems to be the solution that I'm looking for.
With ELK stack (Elasticsearch-Logstash-Kibana) I can only look at the system logs, but I can't make a custom admin area for my users where they can view all the statistics they want, where they can view "beautified" data, where they can hide or show the columns and change the aggregation of the results. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @angelocala94 Kibana is used for that. You can create Pie charts, Graphs, tables etc there based on the data you have. Admins can create personalized Dashboards for their domains and much more. https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana

Comment: @Rahul I don't need Kibana because this is only a small part of a bigger product, so I need to find the low level solutions about these problems that allow me to develop a custom product. I want to use Laravel (PHP) as the framework of my app, or NodeJS if performance are better.

Answer (score 0):

One table per user is a worse mess; don't do that.

Millions of rows a day -- dozens, maybe hundreds, per second?  That probably requires some form of 'staging' -- collecting multiple rows, then batch-inserting them.  Before discussing further, please elaborate on the data flow:  Single vs. multiple clients.  UI vs. batch processes.  Tentative `CREATE TABLE`.  Etc.

Statistical -- Plan on creating and incrementally maintaining "Summary tables".

Are you trying to map user IP addresses to Country?  That is a separate question, and it has been answered.

"Must" "real-time" "milliseconds".  Face it, you will  have to make some trade-offs.

More info:  Go to http://mysql.rjweb.org/ ; from there, see the three blogs on Data Warehouse Techniques.

**How to store by day**

InnoDB stores data in `PRIMARY KEY` order.  So, to get all the rows for one day adjacent to each other, one must *start* the PK with the datetime.  For huge databases, may improve certain queries significantly by allowing the query to scan the data sequentially, thereby minimizing disk I/O.

If you already have `id AUTO_INCREMENT` (and if you continue to need it), then do this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(datetime, id),  -- to get clustering, and be UNIQUE
INDEX(id)  -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

If you have a year's worth of data, and the data won't fit in RAM, then this technique is very effective for small time ranges.  But if your time range is bigger than the cache, you will be at the mercy of I/O speed.

**Maintaining summary tables with changing data**

This *may* be possible; I need to better understand the data and the changes.

You *cannot* scan a million rows in sub-second time, regardless of caching, tuning, and other optimizations.  You *can* do the desired data with a Summary table much faster.

**Shrink the data**

- Don't use `BIGINT` (8 bytes) if `INT` (4 bytes) will suffice; don't use `INT` if `MEDIUMINT` (3 bytes) will do.  Etc.
- Use `UNSIGNED` where appropriate.
- Normalize repeated strings.

Smaller data will make it more cacheable, hence run faster when you do have to hit the disk.

Comment: Since the statistics are to be dynamic, I do not think you can use something like "summary tables".
I think that the problem is not the INSERT statement, but the statistic queries. 
Over time to make queries on large tables becomes so slow...

Comment: I added some more.

Comment: Hi Rick! All these records will be inserted in the same order they arrive, so they are already sequential. I mean that the rows are already ordered by date.

Comment: Maybe I can maintain one summary table for every grouping field.
For example, I want to show the clicks of every landing page.
I can use a table, and save in this table all the clicks already grouped for every landing page, divided by day. So, if i want to show the data for two days, i need only to group two rows for every landing page instead of thousand.

Comment: You have the right idea.  Go with it.  Keep in mind to _incrementally_ update the summary table, don't rebuild it from scratch (except the first time).  And it is often desirable to have 2 or 3 'grouping fields' (plus "day") to define a summary table.  I find that the typical situation needs 3 to 7 different Summary tables.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables